# Extracting IP Data using gethostbyname()

Tags: c++, networking, dns

Now for example if I want to find the IP of a certain host. I would use the gethostbyname() commands and put he data in the struct hostent. Now I wanted to get the information h_addr_list. So what I did was I start printing the the addresses till I got a null character. Now the problem I'm facing is that the addresses are in *char format and I want to change them to IPv4 format. I've tried certain methods but I keep running into problems.

```
struct hostent 
{
    char *h_name;       /* Official domain name of host */
    char **h_aliases;   /* Null-terminated array of domain names */
    int h_addrtype;     /* Host address type (AF_INET) */
    int h_length;       /* Length of an address, in bytes */
    char **h_addr_list;     /* Null-terminated array of in_addr structs */
};
```

Comment: Are you trying to say that you don't know how to convert an IPv4 dotted quad string to some unspecified other format? Where's your code sample?

Comment: What do you mean by "IPv4 format"? Do you mean you want them as a dotted quad string like "127.0.0.1"?

Comment: ^Dotted quad string like 127.0.0.1 Yes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is the example of code. The output address is in the format of digits.digits.digits.digits (it contains dotted)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <netdb.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
struct hostent *he;
struct in_addr a;

int main ()
{
  he = gethostbyname ("localhost");
  if (he)
  {
    printf("name: %s\n", he->h_name);
    while (*he->h_aliases)
        printf("alias: %s\n", *he->h_aliases++);
    while (*he->h_addr_list)
    {
        bcopy(*he->h_addr_list++, (char *) &a, sizeof(a));
        printf("address: %s\n", inet_ntoa(a));
    }
 }
 else
    printf("error");
 return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
name: localhost
address: 127.0.0.1
```

Answer (score 0):

Do want to do something like this:

where Address is char*

```
struct in_addr IpAddress;
if(inet_aton(Address,&IpAddress))
{
    return(ntohl((int)IpAddress.s_addr));
}
```

.